# The seed entity for entity type 'X' cannot be added because the was no value provided for the required property "..ID"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I'm playing wit **EF Core 2.1 Preview 2**.
I have troubles with HasData (Seed) method in `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`

My model is simple POCO class that has no annotation.

```
public class Tenant {
    public int TenantID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

in my `DbContext` inside `OnModelCreating` method is DB model defined as

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>(e => {
    e.HasKey(m => m.TenantID)
     .HasName("PK_Tenants");

    e.Property(m => m.TenantID)
     .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

    e.Property(m => m.Name)
     .IsRequired()
     .HasMaxLength(256);
}
```

and the seed mehod is defined as:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().HasData(new []{
   new Tenant {
      TenantID = 0,
      Name = "SystemTenant",
   }
});
```

---

During startap, when ctx.Database.Migrate() is run, I got exception: 
The seed entity for entity type 'Tenant' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'TenantID

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The exception is little bit misleading. There must be some mechanism inside, that tests required properties so they must be different to a default values.

The only change I had to do was specifying `TenantID != 0`.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().HasData(new []{ 
   new Tenant {
      TenantID = 1, // Must be != 0
      Name = "SystemTenant",
   }
});
```

Comment: after I made the correction I had to a clean and a rebuild of the project in order to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

I have created little "hack" to **bypass 0 PK value restriction** after I reverse engineering the [EF Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore) code and I found [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/0ba65b8dfc9294b714b6855eef340bdfbfb8d64c/src/EFCore/Infrastructure/ModelValidator.cs#L884) line of code.
Related to [@Tomino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010613/the-seed-entity-for-entity-type-x-cannot-be-added-because-the-was-no-value-pro/50010614#50010614) answer.
Here is my snipped extension code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;

namespace EntityFrameworkCore.CustomMigration
{
    public static class CustomModelBuilder
    {
        public static bool IsSignedInteger(this Type type)
           => type == typeof(int)
              || type == typeof(long)
              || type == typeof(short)
              || type == typeof(sbyte);

        public static void Seed<T>(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder, IEnumerable<T> data) where T : class
        {
            var entnty = modelBuilder.Entity<T>();

            var pk = entnty.Metadata
                .GetProperties()
                .FirstOrDefault(property => 
                    property.RequiresValueGenerator() 
                    && property.IsPrimaryKey()
                    && property.ClrType.IsSignedInteger()
                    && property.ClrType.IsDefaultValue(0)
                );
            if (pk != null)
            {
                entnty.Property(pk.Name).ValueGeneratedNever();
                entnty.HasData(data);
                entnty.Property(pk.Name).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
            }
            else
            {
                entnty.HasData(data);
            }          
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this in `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Seed(new List<Tenant> {
        new Tenant() {TenantID = 0 , Name = string.Empty},
        new Tenant() {TenantID = 1 , Name = "test"}
        //....
        );

    //....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error in one of my repositories.

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidOperationException
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 
'The seed entity for entity type 'SubscriptionType'
cannot be added because a default value was provided for the required property 'Id'. 

Please provide a value different from '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.'
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateData(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
```

The issue was that I was using `new Guid()` to assign the values to the `id` field, which was just a mistake. The `new Guid` will just create dummy Guid with all-zeroes whereas the `Guid.NewGuid()` will create the unique Guid. So, I had to use the `Guid.NewGuid()` in my code.

```
builder.Entity<SubscriptionType>(b =>
            {
                b.HasKey(k => k.Id);
                b.HasData(new SubscriptionType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "SeatBased" },
                               new SubscriptionType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "NonSeatBased" },
                               new SubscriptionType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "AzureEntitlement" },
                               new SubscriptionType { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Bundle" });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using a custom service to pull data to database, I did it like this:

`builder.Entity<EntityName>().HasData(someSerive.GetById(id).AsEnumerable());`

I got to change it to `ToArray()`:

`builder.Entity<EntityName>().HasData(someSerive.GetById(id).ToArray());`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, I added a new property to my model class and trying to migrate, I kept `[Required]` attribute to my property and forgot to include the property in my seed data. Please check your model class and seeding data in `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` Method.

Comment: This solved it for me. To be more detailed I have a one to many relationship and I had to add [Required] to the child class properties that pointed to the parent. I could get around with making the properties nulalble, but didn't want to take the easy way out. This allowed the properties to not having to be set in c# 11.

Answer (score 0):

**Limitations** of model seed data:

- Temporary data for testing
- Data that depends on database state
- Data that is large (seeding data gets captured in migration snapshots, and large data can quickly lead to huge files and degraded performance).
- Data that needs key values to be generated by the database, including entities that use alternate keys as the identity
- Data that requires custom transformation (that is not handled by value conversions), such as some password hashing
- Data that requires calls to external API, such as ASP.NET Core Identity roles and users creation

I get "The seed entity for entity type 'Role' cannot be added because a non-zero value is required for property 'Id'. Consider providing a negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data" error when seeding asp.net Identity **Role** , so we should set Id value:

```
namespace Attendance.Server.Data.Configs; 

public class RoleConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Role");
            builder.Property(p => p.Name).IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(p => p.NormalizedName).IsUnicode(false).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(p => p.ConcurrencyStamp).IsUnicode(false);
    
            // seed
            builder.HasData(
                new Role { Id = 1, Name = "admin", NormalizedName = "ADMIN" },
                new Role { Id = 2, Name = "user", NormalizedName = "USER" }
            );
        }
    }
```

my Role **Entity** :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Attendance.Server.Data.Entities;

public partial class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{

}
```

Add all config classes by only one line code with **ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly** method in DbContext :

```
namespace Attendance.Server.Data;

public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>, IUnitOfWork
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        return base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void MarkAsDeleted<TEntity>(TEntity entity) => base.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UserConfig).Assembly);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use nullable field (I mean the question mark after int), something like this:

```cs
public class Tenant 
{
    public int? TenantId {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Not for a primary key....

Comment: This wouldn't represent the actual model from the database. A primary key can't be null.