# The seed entity for entity type 'Publication' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Image'

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to test my app, but I'm getting this error:
`The seed entity for entity type 'Publication' cannot be added because there was no value provided for the required property 'Image'`

The problem is that value is actually provided.

I'm trying to seed some data for testing this way:

```
public static class NewsierContextFactory
    {
        public static NewsierContext Create()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<NewsierContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .Options;

            var dateTimeMock = new Mock<IDateTime>();
            dateTimeMock.Setup(m => m.Now)
                .Returns(new DateTime(3001, 1, 1));

            var context = new NewsierContext(options, dateTimeMock.Object);

            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            context.Publishers.AddRange(
                  new Publisher()
                  {
                      Id = "one",
                      Image = "default-user.png",
                      Name = "Name",
                      Surname = "Surname",
                      Email = "test@email.com",
                      Password = "publisher",
                      Role = "admin",
                      CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                      LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now
                  }
              );

            context.Categories.AddRange(
                new Category()
                {
                    Id = "one",
                    Name = "categ",
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                    LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now
                }
            );

            context.Publications.AddRange(
                new Publication
                {
                    Id = "one",
                    Image = "default-publication.png",
                    Title = "title",
                    Value = "value",
                    Views = 37,
                    CategoryId = "one",
                    PublisherId = "one",
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                    LastModifiedAt = DateTime.Now
                }
            );

            context.SaveChanges();

            return context;
        }

        public static void Destroy(NewsierContext context)
        {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();

            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

As you can see my Publisher entity has the exact value "Image". And also they both have the same config for this value.

```
public class PublisherConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Publisher>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Publisher> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(p => p.Image)
                .HasMaxLength(256)
                .HasDefaultValue("Static/Images/default-user.png")
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(32)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Surname)
                .HasMaxLength(64)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Email)
                .HasMaxLength(128)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Password)
                .HasMaxLength(256)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Role)
                .HasMaxLength(12)
                .HasDefaultValue("publisher")
                .IsRequired();

            builder.HasData(
                new Publisher
                {
                    Id = "publisher-one",
                    Name = "name",
                    Surname = "sur",
                    Email = "admin@newsier.com",
                    Password = "admin",
                    Role = "admin",
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now
                },
                new Publisher
                {
                    Id = "publisher-two",
                    Name = "name",
                    Surname = "sur",
                    Email = "admin@email.com",
                    Password = "publisher",
                    Role = "publisher",
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

```
public class PublicationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Publication>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Publication> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(p => p.Image)
               .HasDefaultValue("default-publication.png")
               .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Title)
                .HasMaxLength(256)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.Value)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.PublisherId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(p => p.CategoryId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.HasOne(p => p.Category)
                .WithMany(categ => categ.Publications)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.HasOne(p => p.Publisher)
                .WithMany(pub => pub.Publications)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            builder.HasData(
                new Publication {
                    Id = "publication-one",
                    Title = "the first publication",
                    Value = "the content of the very first publication on the web-site",
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                    CategoryId = "category-one",
                    PublisherId = "publisher-one"
                },
                new Publication
                {
                    Id = "publication-two",
                    Title = "the second publication",
                    Value = "the content of the second publication on the web-site",
                    CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                    CategoryId = "category-one",
                    PublisherId = "publisher-two"
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Here is my Entities:

```
public class Publisher : BaseEntity
    {
        public Publisher()
        {
            Publications = new HashSet<Publication>();
        }

        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Publication : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public long Views { get; set; }

        public string PublisherId { get; set; }
        public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }

        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

And also the base entity:

```
public class BaseEntity
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModifiedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried to remove the "Image" property from the Publication and the error disappeared, but there is the same "Image" value in the Publisher and it doesn't provide any errors.

How can I fix this and why this is not a problem for the Publicher entity?

And just a thing to mention that migrations work pretty well. It means I can add some data using "HasData", but I can't do the same with "Add" or "AddRange".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think the answer you're looking for is here: [Seed values must be different from default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010613/the-seed-entity-for-entity-type-x-cannot-be-added-because-the-was-no-value-pro)

The reason Publisher works is because the seed value and the `HasData` values for `Image` are different. The Publication ones equate to the same value `default-publication.png` and apparently that makes the seeder think you haven't set it?

Yeah, that made me raise an eye-brow as well.

Comment: Good answer, really, but it doesn't work. I changed my default values and tried to use another value for adding. Also I rebuild my project every time I make changes, but it doesn't work anyway. The default value of the Image property is "default-publication.png" and I use, for fun, the "not-the-same-value-as-default" value trying to add a publication with the help of "AddRange". Nevertheless I have the same error and I think maybe your answer is the solution, but there is another problem, what do you think?

Comment: Never mind, I realized what the problem is. I should have provided a value for `Image` using `HasData` in spite of the default value. I thought that I'm not supposed to do this, because I have a default value. Your answer helped me to realize that.